# CUDA Binary kernel 5.2 error. Fresh Install 2.6

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have never encountered this problem before. Was working in 2.75 and everthing was fine, then I updated to 2.76 (same problem occurs with 2.76b). Now when I try to GPU render in cycles I get this error:
"CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (5.2) not found."
I've google some solutions, one being to rename "kernel_sm_50.cubin" to "kernel_sm_52.cubin" in the "scripts/addons/cycles/lib" directory. But when I look in that folder, I only have kernels 20, 21, 30, 35. In the Blender 2.75 install, there is a kernel_sm_50.cubin AND kernel_sm_52.cubin, so I'm a bit confused why these are not showing up in the new install. 
Any insight would be helpful, this is the first time I've had a error from a fresh install of a new version. I've updated and reinstalled drivers for my video cards to no effect.

Windows 7
AMD FX 8350
GTX 580
GTX 970
Blender 2.76b

Comment: that is very strange indeed. In my install of 2.76 I have both kernel_sm_50.cubin as well as 52... try downloading again or download the  .zip install file  and look for the missing files

Comment: I just downloaded the Zip (Windows 32 bit), and it is missing kernels _50 and _52. Very confusing. I guess I also forgot to mention that I am using the 32bit version of Blender. For whatever reason, the 64bit version always crashes on my 64 bit system, but that is another thread...

Comment: The correct kernels (_50 and _52) are in the 64bit zip of 2.76b, but if I try copying those into a 32bit install file path, I get "CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: Invalid kernel image"

Comment: I don't think mixing 32 and 64 bit installs is a good idea... are you running Windows 7 64 bit?

Comment: There have been issues building cuda kernels on 32 bit (both win and linux) see the history of [this build file](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/history/master/build_files/buildbot/slave_compile.py) I expect you will need to use 64bit version to get gpu rendering support. If the 64bit version always crashes then report that as a bug.

Comment: Yes, I am running a 64bit version of Windows 7, and honestly haven't been able to get a 64 bit version of Blender to run without crashing since 2.6x.- Something i will report as a bug.